# How can you get highlighted text (window.getSelection()) in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have been learning to make a custom markdown editor. However I just ran into the problem of getting the highlighted text before wrapping it with the markdowns. Here's my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/lau_chung/ohdpezxL/8/)

```
class TextArea extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        comment:'He oppose at thrown desire of no. Announcing impression unaffected day his are unreserved indulgence.She oppose at thrown desire of no..'
    };
    this.onClickMakeBold = this.onClickMakeBold.bind(this);
  }

  render(){
    return <div>
       <button onClick={this.onClickMakeBold}>Bold</button> 
         <div>
           <textarea ref="textarea">{this.state.comment}</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
  }

  onClickMakeBold(){
    console.log(getSelectionText()) 
  }
}
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control"){
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }else{
            alert('no')
    }
    return text;
}

React.render(<TextArea />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

The result from `getSelectionText()` function doesn't return any text at all. How can I get the highlighted text in ReactJS?

Comment: You should try DraftJS, super cool editor from Facebook.

Answer (score 4):

By clicking on the button, you deselect the text *before* the event is triggered.

Pass the callback to your button as `onMouseDown`, as this event happens before the standard click side effects take place.

Also: if you want the text to remain selected after the event has been processed, use `event.preventDefault()` in your callback function.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer but I couldn't use event.preventDefault() for this code :( the document.onmouseup does return Nothing  for me too.                                              let doit = () => {
  document.onmouseup = () => {
    let a2 = window.getSelection().toString();
    console.log(a2);
    return a2;  // a2 is empty
  };
};

Answer (score 1):

here is solution with **react hook** pure without any library!

to clone and the small package or any question you can check:
https://github.com/Farbod29/React-text-highlighter-with-hook-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './highlight.css';

export default function Highlighter() {
  const [highlightedText, setHighlightedText] = useState(
    'highlighted text will be shown here!'
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    const saveSelection = () => {
      setHighlightedText(window.getSelection().toString());
    };
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', saveSelection);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('mouseup', saveSelection);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <section className="card">
        <div>
          <div className="margin-top-zero txt">
            Here is react text highlighter with hook and use state/Effect, 
            understand if you have any question just email or add issue in above git ripo!
         
          </div>
          {/* {ghasem} */}
          <div className="txt">{highlightedText}</div>
          <div // parent of button
          >
            <button className="btn"> Add Highlighted text </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}
```